# Change the hooks priority in mongoose

Tags: mongoose, hook, middleware, keystonejs

I have 2 hooks (in different files) on a model like this:

```
model.pre('save', function(next) {
    if (this.isModified('password'))
        this.set('password, hash(this.get('password'))
    next()
})

model.pre('save', function() {
    if (this.isNew)
        this.set('password', generatePassword())
    next()
})
```

My first hook comes from a module, it has to be first and I can't modify it. It checks that the password field was modified and hash it if it was.
My second hook was created by me, I'm setting a random generated password when the user is created.

My problem is that my first hook won't hash my password because it's passed before the second one. I tried to call `this.save` in my second hook but `isModified` is false if I do that.

I had to copy the `hash` function of the first hook into the second file to make it work, but it's far from being perfect.

So I'd like to know if there is a way to run hooks in a priority order in mongoose ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, mongoose does not provide a means to prioritize `pre save` hooks, or any other types of hooks for that matter. However, in your particular use case you may want to consider using the `post validate` hook.

```
model.post('validate', function (doc) {
    if (doc.isNew) {
       doc.set('password', generatePassword());
    }
});
```

`post validate` hooks execute before the document is saved, and before any user-defined `pre save` hooks.